# Python pandas compare 2 dataframe output new/delete/change values in new column

Tags: python, pandas

Lets assume I have below 2 dataframes

```
df1 =

userid  | first_name |  last_name   | title
-----------------------------------------------
u1  |   user1   |   test    |   manager

u2  |   user2   |   test    |   creator

u4  |   user4   |   test    |   Analysts


df2 =

userid |    first_name  |last_name  |title
----------------------------------------------
u1  |   user1   |   test    |   designer
u2  |   user2   |   test    |   creator
u3  |   user2   |   test    |   creator
```

I used panda merge command

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer',on=['userid','first_name','last_name','title'],indicator=True)
```

what i am expecting as a result when comparing df1 with df2

```
userid  |first_name |last_name| title   |    status|
--------------------------------------------------
u1  |   user1   |   test    |       manager |   changed

u2  |   user2   |   test    |   creator |   Nochange

u3  |   user2   |   test    |   creator   |  Deleted

u4  |  user4    |   test    |   Analysts  | New
```

But what i get when i use panda merge

```
userid  |first_name|    last_name|  title   |   _merge

u1  |   user1       |test       |manager    |   left_only

u2  |   user2       |test   |   creator     |both

u3  |   user2       |test   |   creator   |  left_only

u1  |   user1       |test   |   designer |   rigth_only
```

So in the above output i can see the _merge field gives me some data to filter, but I need to find a way identify solution for these 3 below items

1. u1 userid is showing up twice  ( as per the record the 'title' was changed in df1 so i need to show it as 'changed' in the new or _merge column)
2. u3      user2       test        creator -  I need to show up as deleted row
3. u4      user4       test        Analysts  - Need to show up as new row

Any idea how i can achieve the desired output?. Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Do you use title column to check if a record has changed?

Comment: Allen,
I might have like 10 columns with userid as unique and any one of the 9 columns value can change ( not just title).  In this case how do we handle the 'changed' value field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to match the output by breaking the problem into two steps:

1) Group by userid, first_name, last_name and count records. These are the changed records - set _merge indicator to changed.

2) Filter duplicate userid, first_name, last_name records and replace the indicator.

This works if left_only will always be 'New' and right_only will always be 'Deleted' (per the example) and in the notebook, I tried to draw attention to this.   [image]

Interactive:
https://notebooks.azure.com/emican86/libraries/49373439

Static:
https://github.com/emican86/49373439/blob/master/49373439.ipynb

Comment: This is great.. really appreciate the quick response. For the example I gave this is the code i need.
 another question related to this.
If we have like 10 columns with userid as unique and any one of the 9 columns value can changes ( not just title column).  In this case how do we handle the 'changed' value field.

Comment: Please vote/accept as answer:)  You have many options.  Is the output for a person or machine? Creating 3 rows for Old/ New/ Changed or "stacked" records may be fine for a person to read if all 9 columns are being reviewed and are of equal importance.  In general, tailor the output of the report to the action.  If one change is more important than another, a function can be applied to display the important change.  Many options depending on how the report is used.